# Is it possible to modify database using SQL injection with Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sql-injection

Using Rails 4.0 I have a controller action which uses request parameters in an active record query:

```
@clients = Client.where(params[:where]).order(params[:order]).limit(params[:limit])
```

Would it be possible for a user, using sql injection, to modify the database, or obtain information from the database that is not contained in the clients table?

If so an example would be greatly appreciated, as well as a simple method to prevent the possibility (I understand that placeholders or hash parameters would remove the vulnerablity but I don't see how to create the same functionality using them)

Thanks in advance.

***Edit***

I understand that these methods have vulnerabilities.  My question concerns the extent of the vulnerablity.  I was not able to find the answer to my specific question in the rails guides.

Comment: @BradWerth I have already read the two articles referenced in that post and didn't get a definitive answer.  I tried to execute the query given by @messanjah as an example but got the error:  ```PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement```.  perhaps that vulnerability has been patched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `where` method assumes that its argument is a SQL fragment if it's a string.

What happens next probably depends on the database used, for example on mysql 
Active Record turns off the ability for a query to contain multiple statements, so it's not just a case of injecting a where clause with a ';'.

Current versions of rails use prepared statements on postgres, which also forbids the injection of multiple statements.

In general relying on this seems extremely risky and may vary on other databases. Even if data modification / theft is not possible, denial of service would be trivial.

It would also be possible to steal information of the form "is there a user with email address xyz" by using a subquery that uses `EXISTS`. With a little time an patience you could also extract values, for example if I know a user's id and want to extract their email address I could run subselects of the form

```
SELECT * from users where id = 123 and email_address like 'A%'
```

If I get results then I know the email address starts with A, and I can move onto the next letter. If not then I check whether the email address starts with B and so on. Once I've got the first character, then queries of the form

```
SELECT * from users where id = 123 and email_address like 'FA%'
SELECT * from users where id = 123 and email_address like 'FB%'
SELECT * from users where id = 123 and email_address like 'FC%'
```

allow me to extract the second character of the email address. With a few thousand queries you could get their whole email address.

Another way to do this would be to use the `sleep` function on mysql - it would allow the extraction of variables one byte at a time based on how long the page took to load

Answer (score 1):

You can found your response here: http://rails-sqli.org/

This website lists many query methods and options in ActiveRecord which do not sanitize raw SQL arguments and are not intended to be called with unsafe user input

Comment: So is the answer to my question "yes" or "no"?

Comment: The response is no. Placeholders are enough to prevent injections. You can't use functions inside placeholders, and you can't use placeholders as column or table names, because they are escaped and quoted as string literals.

Comment: Placeholders are safe against SQL injection as long as you don't pass them raw SQL strings !

Comment: thanks for your help.  My question concerns raw SQL strings not placeholders.